# Serialize a decimal to a human readable currency format

Tags: c#, json, serialization, currency

I am using `json.net` library to serialize an object which has a decimal value that represents a cost. When serializing, I want the json to look something like `'$400,000'` instead of `'400000.0'`.

Is there a way that I can accomplish this in an easy and efficient way? This object contains many other secondary objects and subsequent properties.

The application will be used locally and the specs say that the output should be in human readable format. Culture variance isn't of any importance in this context.

Comment: Why?  JSON is an _electronic_ interchange format and not necessarily designed for readability.  If you want formatted values use a `string` instead of a `decimal`.

Comment: I'd agree with not serialising in anything other than an invariant culture. What if [NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyGroupSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencygroupseparator) is, say, "." like it is for most of Europe? Do you serialise in the current culture so it's correct for whoever *wrote* the file, or do you serialise it in, say, "en-US", alienating those who don't use dollars, those who don't use the comma, etc? As soon as you *format* data to serialise it, you are opening yourself up to a world of hurt. (I'm speaking from experience).

Comment: You would need to serialize your property as a string since the [JSON standard for numerical values](http://json.org/) is very simple, culture-invariant, and does not allow for any sort of currency prefix.  Also, second the warning of @WaiHaLee that you're likely to create a file that cannot be read by people in other locales.

Comment: Try looking at [Humanizer](http://humanizr.net). It can convert almost anything to human readable format. Specifically for your scenario though, you can just `ToString("C")`

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to perform this since you can't work around a fact that serializer is directly accessing your properties.

If you need a formatted JSON output I would recommend writing a helper class that wraps the class you want to expose. Unfortunately I've done this once for some XML report and really the easiest way went something like this:

```
class PersonXml
{
   Person _person;

   void PersonXml(Person person) { _person = person; }

   string Age { get { return _person.Age + " years"; } }
}
```

This is just a simple example I wrote on the fly but the principle is always the same. Even if some advanced JSON serializer offered me ways to format my output, I'd really keep this concept out of my main objects in a separate file with separate helper classes.

Again this isn't quite the solution, in my opinion it should never come to this but if it does, this is the lesser of the evils in my experience.

Also, just note that if you reference the class in your property getters there's a danger of null reference.

Answer (score 0):

As D Stanley suggested, I changed the field type to string from decimal as data in it was only being read and not used for data manipulation.